# ls: Dereference symlink but retain color

Tags: linux, shell, ls

Hopefully as simple as it sounds. The problem with `ls -alL` is that it references the original file, so it no longer colors the output as a symlink.

Essentially, I just want to get rid of the link in the output - from the arrow onward e.g. `.vimrc -> .dotfiles/vim/.vimrc`

It's really just for sake of aesthetics. My alternative would be to find a way to group the symlinks, so I can turn this:

```
.tmux.conf -> .dotfiles/tmux/.tmux.conf
.tmuxinator -> .dotfiles/tmuxinator/.tmuxinator
.vim
.viminfo
.vimrc -> .dotfiles/vim/.vimrc
Folder
```

into this:

```
.vim
.viminfo
.tmux.conf -> .dotfiles/tmux/.tmux.conf
.tmuxinator -> .dotfiles/tmuxinator/.tmuxinator
.vimrc -> .dotfiles/vim/.vimrc
Folder
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: they should  be green by default, red if broken

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unix & linux

Answer (score 1):

Try piping the output through a program like `sed` or `perl` and use the substitute regex to get rid of what you don't want like`| perl -pe 's/(.*?)->.*/$1/'`

Comment: I'm not an expert on perl or sed so my regex syntax might be wrong.

Comment: And you can use an alias in your `.bashrc` file so that you don't have to type it out all the time.

Comment: The problem is that piping to things like sed, grep, perl, etc. strip the coloring.

Comment: I know, but there's no option listed in the man page that does what you want. :(